# How to remove duplicates from list of objects(according to value inside object), choosing item from dup’s according to other value inside object?

Tags: python, arrays, list, object

so basically, I have a list of objects. Let's say each object has two properties: A and B. A is a tuple of 3 integers: (A1, A2, A3), and B is an integer. This list may contain objects that have identical A's, and I want to get rid of those duplicates. However, I want to do so in a way that among those objects that have the same A, the one with the lowest B is chosen. In the end, I want a list of objects with all unique A's and with the lowest B's.

I thought about it for a while, and I think I can come up with a really janky way to do this with lots of for loops, but I feel like there must be a much better way built into a function in python or in some sort of library (to do at least a part of this). Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

edit: For more detail, this is actually for a tetris AI, for finding all possible moves with a given piece. My objects are nodes in a tree of possible Tetris moves. Each node has two values: A: (x_position, y_position, rotation), and B: the number of frames it takes to reach that position. I start with a root node at the starting position. At each step, I expand the tree by making children by doing one move to the left, one move to the right, one rotation left, one rotation right, or one softdrop downward, and for each child I update both A, the XYR position, and B, the number of frames it took to get there. I add all these to a list of potential moves. After this, I merge all nodes that have the same XYR position, choosing the node that has the least frames to get there. The next step, I expand each node inside of the list of potential moves and repeat the process. Sorry, I realize this explanation might be confusing, which is why I didn't include it in the original explanation. I think it's advantageous to do it this way because in modern tetris, there is a rather complicated rotation system called SRS (Super Rotation System) that allows you to perform complicated spins with various pieces, so by making a pathfinder in this way and simulating the piece making the moves according to SRS is a good way since it tells you if the move was a spin or not (sending more/less dmg), and it also allows you to know the exact movement to execute the placement (I also store a list of series of moves to reach that position) with the least frames. Later, I want to be able to figure out how to hash the states properly so I don't revisit, but I'm still figuring it out.

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you actually gave an example of actual data, and the actual result that your process would produce.

Comment: Ok, I'll update it now.

Comment: I think with "actual data" @DavidBuck did not mean a very long *description* of the data. :)

Comment: You think correctly @timgeb

Comment: Ahh, sorry yall lol. I won't update it now since Mustafa gave a working answer, but I'll keep it in mind next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {}
for obj in the_list:
    current_lowest = d.setdefault(obj.A, obj)
    if obj.B < current_lowest.B:
        d[obj.A] = obj

# Get the result
desired_list = list(d.values())
```

We have a dict `d` whose keys are tuples (`A`) and values are objects themselves. The `.setdefault` ensures that if the `A` of interest is not seen yet, it sets it with the current object `obj`. If it was seen already, it returns the value (an object) corresponding to that `A`. Then we compare that object's `B` with the one at hand and act dependingly. At the end, the desired result will lie in the values of `d`.

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful! I didn't think of using a dictionary. In fact, I'm thinking it may be better to just turn my list into a dictionary altogether and using this method every time we add another object.